# Unable to update variable in build yaml on condition

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, yaml

I'm trying to implement a simple counter to increment the minor version on every build.

I have the following:

```
variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  major: 1
  minor: 0

- powershell: |
            if ("$(Build.SourceBranch)".Contains('master')) 
            {
              Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=minor;]$[counter(variables['minor'], 0)]"
              echo $(minor)
            }
            else
            {
              echo "not on main"
            }
```

But the echo always prints 0

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

> Unable to update variable in build yaml on condition

That is because the variable we set with [Logging Commands](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md) will take effect in the **next** task, not in the current task.

In you case, the variable `minor` always shows the value we set in Variables.

To resolve this issue, we could set another variable as incremental variable:

```
variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  major: 1
  minor: 0
  increminor: $[counter(variables['minor'], 0)]
```

Then the task like:

```
- powershell: |
            if ("$(Build.SourceBranch)".Contains('master')) 
            {
              Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=minor;]$(increminor)"
       
            }
            else
            {
              echo "not on main"
            }

- script: echo $(minor)
  displayName: 'Test increminor'
```

Comment: wouldn't that increment the "increminor" on every build instead of every build that's a "release"?